# Zigzag line in View

Tags: android, android-layout

Is their a way to draw a straight zigzag line. I've tried using shape still no luck any help if possible[image: like in this image]

Comment: why don't you just use image!

Comment: Why without image is not possible ?

Comment: I didn't say it's not possible, it can be achieved by shapes but i meant for easy and more efficient implementation!

Comment: But instead of loading image, drawable would be more efficient.

Comment: Use SVG image for this